# Glassfish 3.1.1 enable-secure-admin fails

Tags: glassfish, administration

I installed the last stable version of `glassfish 3.1.1` multilingual on windows 7. Currently I am trying to setup a cluster with several instances. I am following the tutorial on  http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/glassfish-3-1-clustering-tutorial/ to do that. In one of the steps I have to use the `enable-secure-admin` command on the `DAS`. However, when I run it it  gives me the following message:

```
C:\glassfish3\bin>asadmin.bat enable-secure-admin
remote failure: Error enabling secure admin : org.jvnet.hk2.config.TransactionFailure: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgument
Exception: Could not find the alias s1as in the trust store
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find the alias s1as in the trust store
Command enable-secure-admin failed.
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to resolve that?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GlassFish Server ships with a certificate to secure communication between the DAS and the remote instances. Make sure you have a keystore.jks file in $GF_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/config directory (assuming your domain is domain1).

If the keystore exists, then make sure s1as exists.  Here's my output:

> $ **keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks**
>   
> Enter keystore password:
>
> Keystore type: JKS
>   Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 2 entries
>
> glassfish-instance, Jul 19, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry, 
>   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 19:E3:36:F6:2E:DA:7C:E0:6A:17:18:19:19:71:86:61
>   **s1as**, Jul 19, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
>  
>   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B1:0D:11:F9:5C:CD:FB:FA:B3:E5:D9:35:9D:44:02:EE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. While resolving the problem I have also tried to run the update tool. But the updatetool was not starting with the error describes here: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14769
One of the solution to make the updatetool runnable is to install the following packages:

- compat-libstdc++
- compat-libgcc
- 32-bit libidn (the one with i386 in the RPM name)

After I make that I have also deleted GlassFish and install Glassfish again ... And "asadmin enable-secure-admin" works! :-)

I had also registered that without the above installed packages the keystore.jks don't contains the "glassfish-instance" certificate. After reinstall GlassFish with the three packages above the keystore.jks contains the "glassfish-instance" certificate. So I assume that the error message "Could not find the alias s1as in the ..." is not right and should be in this case "Could not find the alias glassfish-instance in the ..."